# T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE error

Tags: php, diff

I'm trying to put the diff script into my website, from Paul Butler's website here: http://paulbutler.org/archives/a-simple-diff-algorithm-in-php/

and it gives me the error

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE,
>   expecting ']'  on line 138

line 38 is this

```
$matrix[$oindex][$nindex] = isset($matrix[$oindex - 1][$nindex - 1])
```

More lines before and after are:

```
 function diff($OLDHISTORY, $NEWHISTORY){
     $maxlen = 0;
     foreach($OLDHISTORY as $oindex => $ovalue){
         $nkeys = array_keys($NEWHISTORY, $ovalue);
         foreach($nkeys as $nindex){
             // vvv ERROR LINE vvv
             $matrix[$oindex][$nindex] = isset($matrix[$oindex - 1][$nindex - 1]) ?
                                          $matrix[$oindex - 1][$nindex - 1] + 1 : 1;
             if($matrix[$oindex][$nindex] > $maxlen){
                 $maxlen = $matrix[$oindex][$nindex];
                 $omax = $oindex + 1 - $maxlen;
                 $nmax = $nindex + 1 - $maxlen;
             }
         }
     }
     if($maxlen == 0)
         return array(array('d'=>$OLDHISTORY, 'i'=>$NEWHISTORY));
     return
         array_merge(
             diff(
                 array_slice($OLDHISTORY, 0, $omax),
                 array_slice($NEWHISTORY, 0, $nmax)
             ),
             array_slice($NEWHISTORY, $nmax, $maxlen),
             diff(
                 array_slice($OLDHISTORY, $omax + $maxlen),
                 array_slice($NEWHISTORY, $nmax + $maxlen)
             )
          );
 }
```

Comment: The [codepad of the git blob](http://codepad.org/QFzUYjKy) gives no parse errors; are you sure you've copied it correctly?

Comment: positive, I copy/pasted it... but then I'm a beginner and confused about the script in general... I changed the values of $old and $new to the ones I need for my script, but nothing else, but no one's been able to tell me what else might need changing... do i need to define oindex and nindex maybe?

Comment: Can you post the lines above 138? e.g. 135 - 138.

Comment: lines 133 (beginning) to 138 are:

function diff($OLDHISTORY, $NEWHISTORY){
 $maxlen = 0;
 foreach($OLDHISTORY as $oindex => $ovalue){
  $nkeys = array_keys($NEWHISTORY, $ovalue);
  foreach($nkeys as $nindex){
   $matrix[$oindex][$nindex] = isset($matrix[$oindex - 1][$nindex - 1]) ?

Comment: From what I can discern, there is nothing fundamentally wrong with the code itself, only when it's added to the rest of the page code... any possible reason for that?

Comment: Can you edit more of your code into your question? Not just a few lines before line `138`, but also a few lines after, and the lines **before** you add that function definition. (Posting it as a comment means we can't see how it was originally formatted).

Comment: In that case, there is nothing wrong with that line, there is something wrong with where you are pasting it into your own code; the error just manifests itself there because that's where the parser gives up. FYI, you don't need to change the names of the variables within the function to make it work for your code; it will work anyway. Have a good read of the manual first, specifically the [section on functions](http://php.net/manual/en/language.functions.php).

Comment: Thanks, I added more info now, only saw these comments now. Could it be something to do with the fact that it's put into a table? And thanks for the link, I'm still learning about all the scripting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it, I forgot to close the echo between an html part and the function part. Shows up now, still not working right but I'm getting there